# (remote rejected) master -> master (pre-receive hook declined), Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, openshift

I know that there's couple posts like this one, but solution of any of them works for me.

Here is what I receive when I go for git push heroku master:

[image]

Please support. Ignoring node_modules is not working.

Docpad app - package.json file is updated according to docpad's manual.

I also have Procfile set up as in the link above.

PS. I have tried to deploy docpad app via openshift, but while Im going with manual from http://docpad.org/docs/deploy/ I receive error at step 5.

The application 'appname' is configured for git reference deployments but the
artifact provided ('https://github.com/myusername/appname#master') is a url.
Please provide a git reference to deploy (branch, tag or commit SHA1) or
configure your app to deploy from binaries with 'rhc configure-app appname
--deployment-type binary'.

If I configure myapp to deployment-type binary it isnt working neither.

Comment: Look like you have errors in your node.js file. **read the error**

Comment: In which file percisely? What should I look for?

Comment: Read the error log which you have just printed out here.

Comment: I've read it couple of times and I cant understand whats wrong.. I thought at first that something is wrong with plugin blah and I've installed it just to be sure but it didnt help at all. Im sorry, I dont know what else to do.

Comment: Writing to you as answer

Comment: CodeWizard - perhaps you know whats wrong with my OpenShift deployment? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The plugin which heroku tries to install returned `404` and the installation fails due to that.

Verify that the plugin is indeed public and not something you have wrote or used locally.

There is no package with this name hosted on the registry you use.

[image]

Comment: Ok, but this doesnt provide me solution - I have no control on that, Heroku just tries to install this, and I dont know how to prevent that. I updated my package.json file and removed line "docpad-plugin-blah": "2" but it doesnt help.

Comment: Its probably inside one of your `package.json` files.

Comment: I have only one package.json file and it doesnt contain anything like package blah. Dont know where else to look.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line with `"docpad-plugin-blah": "2"` from your package.json file. That line was provided in the docs simply to show you how to install plugins, but there's no such plugin as `blah`.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "docpad": "6"
 },
```

I strongly recommend that you read through the [Getting Started](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-overview.html) on OpenShift to get an overview of the development workflow using Git.

That being said, and if you really meant to use git reference deployments and you know why you are using them, then read through the [Managing Deployments](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-deployments.html) section on the developers page of OpenShift and find out how to properly set up git reference deployments. For instance, 'https://github.com/myusername/appname#master' is not a valid git url and therefore it cannot be cloned.